# Is there a natural, purely group-theoretic definition of the virtual braid group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, braid-groups, virtual-knots

The braid group $B_n$ has the well-known presentation $$\left<\sigma_i,i=1\ldots n-1\, \left| \begin{cases}\sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_j\sigma_i & |i-j|>1\\\sigma_i\sigma_j\sigma_i=\sigma_j\sigma_i\sigma_j& |i-j|=1\end{cases} \right.\right>$$

Adding the relations $\sigma_i^2=1$ yields the symmetric group $\mathfrak S_n$, and we have a quotient map $B_n\twoheadrightarrow \mathfrak S_n$.

Now the virtual braid group $VB_n$ has a presentation involving

- generators $\sigma_i$ subject to the $B_n$ relations as above,
- generators $\tau_i$ subject to the $\mathfrak S_n$ relations as above ($B_n$ relations and nilpotency),
- mixed relations, which can be written as $$\begin{cases}\sigma_i\tau_j=\tau_j\sigma_i & |i-j|>1\\\tau_i\sigma_j\tau_i=\tau_j\sigma_i\tau_j& |i-j|=1\end{cases}$$

This definition is natural from a graphical and topological point of view, considering either the braid diagrams or their encoding via Gauss codes.

> **What would be a natural way to arrive at this definition, purely from group-theoretic considerations?**
>
> In other words, given a group $G=\left<g\,|\,r\right>$ and a quotient $H=\left<\tilde g\,|\,r\cup s\right>$, can one naturally build a group $V_{\!H}G$ (generated by a set of $g$ generators together with a set of virtual $\tilde g$ generators) where all group-theoretic properties of virtual braids are met?

Such properties would include:

- the map $G\to V_{\!H}G : g_i\mapsto
   g_i$ is injective
- there is a map $V_{\!H}G\to H$ defined by $g_i\mapsto \tilde g_i$ and $\tilde g_i\mapsto \tilde g_i$
- there is a map $V_{\!H}G\to H$ defined by $g_i\mapsto 1$ and $\tilde g_i\mapsto \tilde g_i$
- mixed relations are homogeneous in the case where all relations in $G$ are
- ...

Mixed relations should be obtained by virtualizing *some* generators in *some* relations (ideally, a natural group-theoretic construction should not depend on a presentation, but as of today I don't really have hope that this can be achieved). The four properties listed above already explain why some forbidden mixed relations are forbidden, but not all of them: for instance, $\sigma_1\tau_2\sigma_1=\tau_2\sigma_1\sigma_2$ does not hold, although it would not prevent the two maps $VB_n\to \mathfrak{S}_n$ from being well-defined, it is homogeneous, and *I don't believe* that it would prevent $B_n$ from naturally injecting into $VB_n$.